# How to validate the data entered in dynamically created textBoxes in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a Shiny App. I have an issue with it. How to validate the data entered in textBoxes which are created dynamically. (i.e) only numeric input is allowed. No special characters or numbers greater than 100 and lesser than 0 is allowed to enter.

The **RCode** used is as follows:

```
    require(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
  fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3"))))
)

# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  if(!(is.numeric(x))){ x = 0}
  if(x > 100){
    x = 0
  }
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{
    input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count), function(i) {
      inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
      textInputRow<-function (inputId,value) {
        textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal")
      }
      column(4,textInputRow(inputName, ""))
    })
    do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)

  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})

  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })

  output$text3 <- renderText({getvalues()})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

The above code produces error. Can anyone help me with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to print the error message if the validation fails but using `req` in your code you can validate. Please check the below code:

```
require(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
  fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3"))))
)

# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  if(!(is.numeric(x))){ x = 0}
  if(x > 100){
    x = 0
  }
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{
    input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count), function(i) {
      inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
      textInputRow<-function (inputId,value) {
        #textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal")
         numericInput(inputName,"",1,0,100)
      }
      column(4,textInputRow(inputName, ""))
    })
    do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)

  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})



  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      #validate(need(is.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]),"Please enter a number"))
      req(is.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) & input[[paste0("id",lim)]] > 0 & input[[paste0("id",lim)]] <100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })

  output$text3 <- renderText({getvalues()})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Edit for `req` expression:

```
  req(as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) > 0 & as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) <100)
```

Output screenshot:

[image]

Updated Answer to replace char with 0:

```
require(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui = fluidPage( useShinyjs(), 
  fluidRow(
    column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
  fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3"))))
)

# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  if(!(is.numeric(x))){ x = 0}
  if(x > 100){
    x = 0
  }
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  reactiveValues( initial_val = 0)

  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{
    input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count), function(i) {
      inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
      textInputRow<-function (inputId,value) {
        #textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", value = changed_input(), height = "43px", resize = "horizontal")
        numericInput(inputName,"",0,0,100)
      }
      column(4,textInputRow(inputName, ""))
    })
    do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)

  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})



  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      #validate(need(is.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]),"Please enter a number"))
      #ifelse()
      #ifelse(grepl('^[0-9]*$',input[[paste0("id",lim)]]),cat('cool'),reset(paste0("id",lim)))
      if(!grepl('^[0-9]*$',input[[paste0("id",lim)]])){
        reset(paste0("id",lim))
      }
      req(is.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) & input[[paste0("id",lim)]] > 0 & input[[paste0("id",lim)]] <100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })

  output$text3 <- renderText({getvalues()})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is it possible for textAreaInput to perform validation?

Comment: You would like to keep the textAreaInput instead of numericInput?

Comment: Yes. Also with the above code I can enter characters also in numeric input.

Comment: Sorry, a bit unclear. You also want to enter characters in the textbox? so why do we have to validate it for only numeric if this functionality is requried

Comment: If you use textAreaInput, you can use the edited req

Comment: The value to be entered in the textBox should be only numeric. If any special characters or alphabets are entered means it should not accept those values. Also one can enter the values  between 0 and 100 only.

Comment: That's something the code does with ```numericInput``` but if you still would like to use `textAreaInput` then you can use the new edited `req` expression i've updated in the answer. Please check if that works for you.

Comment: It shows warning after you enter values in the text boxes? Because it's working for me and i tried in IE. So for that purpose why not use the code with numericInput?

Comment: It shows warning after the value is entered. I need in textBoxes only

Comment: I've updated the output screenshot. Could you please update the screenshot of warning?

Comment: Instead of not displaying the sum in textOutput if we entered characters in textBox, is there any solution of automatically updating the textAreaInput if any characters are entered?

Comment: Instead of sum, if characters are entered, then the character should be displayed?

Comment: Noo.. For instance if "a" is entered in textAreaInput it should automatically update that box with value 0. Is it clear?

Comment: Let me check, if any character is entered the value should become 0 right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157461/discussion-between-amrrs-and-nevedha-ayyanar).